# Accessing a Variable from Within a Doubly Nested Function in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, nested-function

The following code:

```
x = 0
print "Initialization: ", x
def f1():
    x = 1
    print "In f1 before f2:", x
    def f2():
        global x
        x = 2
        print "In f2:          ", x
    f2()
    print "In f1 after f2: ", x
f1()
print "Final:          ", x
```

prints:

```
Initialization:  0
In f1 before f2: 1
In f2:           2
In f1 after f2:  1
Final:           2
```

Is there a way for `f2` to access `f1`'s variables?

Comment: This is a dreadful thing.  Why are you trying to do this?  Why not just make `f1` a callable object and properly share instance variables?

Comment: I agree, it is very dreadful, but I was wondering if it was possible. I would hope that nobody would put something like this out in the wild.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the variables, the problem is the assignment. In Python 2 there is no way to rebind `x` to a new value. See [PEP 227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) (nested scopes) for more on this.

In Python 3 you can use the new `nonlocal` keyword instead of `global`. See [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, you can define x as [nonlocal](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) in f2.

In Python 2, you can't assign directly to f1's x in f2. However, you can read its value and access its members. So this could be a workaround:

```
def f1():
    x = [1]
    def f2():
        x[0] = 2
    f2()
    print x[0]
f1()
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `global` statement:

```
>>> x
0
>>> def f1():
    x = 1
    print(x)
    def f2():
        print(x)
    f2()
    print(x)


>>> f1()
1
1
1
```

if you want to **change** variable `x` from `f1` then you need to use `global` statement in each function.

Comment: That won't allow you to assign to x from f2.

Comment: that was fixed, interjay. However, from the question it is not clear that OP wants to assign to `x`. He says *access*.